# When there are multiple consumers of a queue in ActiveMQ, are they all delivered the same messages as they arrive on the queue?

Tags: activemq-classic

What I'm seeing seems strange to me. Not all consumers of a queue are being delivered the messages. Is there a setting I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the nature of JMS Queues to deliver in a round-robin fashion. It may seem strange at first, but it gives you load balancing for free. If you require all consumers to receive the messages, consider using a topic or durable topic. Hope that helps.

Here is a short but sweet [comparison of Queues vs Topics](http://activemq.apache.org/how-does-a-queue-compare-to-a-topic.html)

Comment: Perfect. That explains it nicely. Thank you!